# sqlalchemy: order of query result unexpected

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with MySQL and have a table with two foreign keys:

```
class CampaignCreativeLink(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'campaign_creative_links'
  campaign_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('campaigns.id'),
    primary_key=True)
  creative_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('creatives.id'),
    primary_key=True)
```

Then I use a for loop to insert 3 items into the table like this:

```
session.add(8, 3)
session.add(8, 2)
session.add(8, 1)
```

But when I checked the table, the items are ordered reversely

```
8 1
8 2
8 3
```

And the query shows the order reversely too. What's the reason for this and how can I keep the order same as when they were added?

Answer (score 1):

A table is a **set** of rows and are therefore not guaranteed to have any order unless you specify `ORDER BY`.

In MySQL (InnoDB), the primary key acts as the clustered index. This means that the rows are physically stored in the order specified by the primary key, in this case `(campaign_id, created_id)`, regardless of the order of insertion. This is *usually* the order the rows are returned in if you don't specify an `ORDER BY`.

If you need your rows returned in a certain order, specify `ORDER BY` when you query.

Comment: Does it help to add an `id` field in this table?

Comment: @lang2 Yes, I think that works, if you have an auto-incrementing non-primary key column and always sort on that.

Comment: I did try to add and `id` field but got `Field 'id' doesn't have a default value` error message afterwards.

Comment: @lang2 Did you specify `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `id` column?